# Google maps takes long time to load

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, pug

I am using Google Maps with my web application to plot the route traveled by field officers.

It takes long time to load and plot the Google Maps.

Can you give suggestions to make load Google Maps faster?

I already tried using below js: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=A****************************R&sensor=false"

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You can't.

Long version: Google maps is fairly data heavy. It takes a lot of downloads before it can load into the page; even the official version takes a few seconds. The only way to perceptibly increase the loading speed is to increase your wifi connection speed, then the downloads come faster and the map can load sooner.

Comment: Is it possible to download particular region..??Instead of downloading full map??

Comment: The API does that already. It downloads the relevant area and displays it, then carries on with downloading the rest